# How to position the bootstrap carousel controls to the extreme right and extreme left?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image slider and I want the right and left controls to be positioned to the extreme right and extreme left respectively. and it should work for all widths.

Is that possible ??

Comment: Please post some sample code - makes it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can update the element style

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-next {
  right: 0;  //or you can increase this
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .icon-prev {
  left: 0; //or you can increase this
}
```

Comment: Thanks soo much guys. All your answers work fine. But I can accept only 1 unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

You can change their positioning by changing `carousel-control`'s width. In my view, 4% is great. You can change it to whatever you want.

```
.carousel-control {
    width: 4%
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Having checkout out the [sample code on Bootstrap's docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), it looks like a very simple CSS tweak:

```
.carousel-control.left .glyphicon {
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.carousel-control.right .glyphicon {
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--            Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="mainHomeCarouse" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="mainHomeCarouse" role="button" data-slide="next"> </a>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
```