# Bootstrap 4 carousel slider arrows alignment

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, bootstrap-4, slide

I'm using **Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6** carousel plugin to interactive a div slider.

I want the right and left transparent buttons to be positioned to the extreme right and extreme left respectively, as shown in the image below.

[image]

I have tried changing the position and followed [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316645/how-to-position-the-bootstrap-carousel-controls-to-the-extreme-right-and-extreme) method, but all does not work for my case.

```
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-next {
  right: 0;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .icon-prev {
  left: 0;
}
```

Does anyone have a recommendation for the best way to handle this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 dosen't use glyphicon's, and the framework as a whole has been rewritten in this newer version. This means that carousel snippets for bootstrap 3 likely won't work in Bootstrap 4.

The left and right arrows in the Bootstrap 4 Alpha are tied to the `icon-prev` and `icon-next` classes.

Therefore you can set them to be positioned to the extreme right and extreme left respectively with this code.

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev{
  left: 5px
}
.carousel-control .icon-next{
  right: 5px
}
```

Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/EbbOXd?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks, That helps me a lot!
Is it possible to keep the `icon-prev` and `icon-next` buttons display, when I use **4.0.0-alpha.6** CSS framework?

Comment: @Yi-TingLiu that's correct, `icon-prev` and `icon-next` are  supported in the 4.0.0-alpha.6 CSS framework. :)